# Materialized views in oracle

Tags: oracle, view

How are materialized views implemented in oracle? I've created a materialized view in oracle. What I now see is a quite normal table with a job. Are materialized views translated into tables & jobs in oracle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A materialized view in Oracle is a combination of a structure to hold the data (a table), a job that refreshes the data (a job), and a process that figures out how to refresh the data based on the specified query.  This process would generally involve the creation and maintenance of materialized view logs on the base table to track changes so that the materialized view can be refreshed incrementally though that is technically optional.  It is also common to organize multiple materialized views into refresh groups so that the materialized views themselves are transactionally consistent with each other.

The [Materialized View Concepts and Architecture](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm#i34980) chapter of the Advanced Replication manual is a good place to start reading up about this sort of thing.

Comment: wow, great answer! Are you oracle?

Comment: do you know any resources describing this in more detail? (especially about the refresh groups)?

Comment: @lewap - Added a link to some documentation

Comment: The job is also optional as materialized views can be refreshed on commit or on demand as the referenced documentation indicates.